# Firebase Analytics VIEW_ITEM_LIST ITEMS not showing

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I am trying to report a [VIEW_ITEM_LIST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#view_item_list) event with some [ITEMS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#items) inside. Everything is reported properly in the Debug View except for the items. I am not using any custom event. It seems to happen the same problem in both Android and iOS.

Here is my code.

```
 override fun trackListViewEvent() {
    val eventBundle = Bundle().apply {
        val itemBundle1 = Bundle().apply {
            putString(Param.ITEM_NAME, "name1")
            putString(Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Category")
            putString(Param.PRICE, "49.95")
            putString(Param.CURRENCY, "EUR")
        }

        val itemBundle2 = Bundle().apply {
            putString(Param.ITEM_NAME, "name2")
            putString(Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Category")
            putString(Param.PRICE, "89.95")
            putString(Param.CURRENCY, "EUR")
        }
            putString(Param.ITEM_LIST_ID, "1234567890")
            putString(Param.ITEM_LIST_NAME, "WhateverListName")
            putString(Param.PRICE, "125.60")
            putString(Param.CURRENCY, "EUR")

            putParcelableArray(Param.ITEMS, arrayOf(itemBundle1, itemBundle2))
        }
    tracking.logEvent(Event.VIEW_ITEM_LIST, eventBundle)
}
```

In the Logcat I get: `W/FA-SVC: Param value can't be null: items`

Another problem is that it seems that ITEMS only accepts some parameters. When adding custom parameters I get `E/FA: Item cannot contain custom parameters`, but when adding NOT custom parameters like FLIGHT_NUMBER I get the same error. And I could not find any explanation on the documentation on which parameters are accepted.

Comment: Try this
putParcelableArray(Param.ITEMS, arrayOf("itemBundle1", "itemBundle2"))

Comment: @MuhammadHasanIrshad I don't think sending an array of strings would solve the problem...

Comment: @NilOleart which version of Analytics are you using?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes firebase                 : [
                    config     : '17.0.0',
                    core       : '17.2.1',
                    messaging  : '20.1.0',
                    performance: '19.0.3'
            ]

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but consider replacing the `core` package with `analytics`, as recommended on the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Comment: Also, I've updated my answer with a possible solution. Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on this for some months so I can shed some light in case anyone is having similar problems:

1. Items are not shown in the debug view but they arrive correctly at GTM (if there is not any problem)
2. About errors: [firebase updated its errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors) and now error 23 (and some more) appears.
3. Enhanced ecommerce does not accept custom parameters and there is not a list of accepted parameters, so follow the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce) to see what parameters can be used.
4. To put a list of items in a bundle use:

> Bundle().apply{
> putParcelabelArray(Param.ITEMS, bundleList.toTypedArray()}

During this months some parameters and events have been deprecated. So you should constantly check if there are any changes.
Keep in mind that firebase analytics for web + app will be released soon, maybe it's a good idea implementing directly web + app.

Answer (score 4):

The example code from Google ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#ITEMS)) written in Java, converts to this code in Kotlin

```
val item1 = Bundle()
item1.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "jeggings")
item1.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "pants")
val item2 = Bundle()
item2.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "boots")
item2.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "shoes")

parameters.putParcelableArray(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, arrayOf(item1, item2))
```

This does not work: on Emulator I got firebase error 25 and on a device it did not show at all in DebugView). You have to infer the Parcelable. So change the last line to below and you should be fine!

```
parameters.putParcelableArray(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, arrayOf<Parcelable>(item1, item2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using is a map to a String array list which is not supported. Take a look at [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/17v1TeX1KK8/gGbVR5zoDwAJ) in the firebase google group.

You should log only numeric or string types for event parameters. So in your case, you can store your data as a string to convert JSON string.

**Note**: String, long and double param types are supported. String parameter values can be up to 100 characters long.
 for more information see [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-methods).

Comment: So the sample code in the documentation for items is not usable? What is the point of using items then? How would you solve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

## New answer:

The problem is you're creating `itemBundle1` and `itemBundle2` inside `eventBundle`'s `apply` function and by the time you call `putParcelableArray(Param.ITEMS, arrayOf(itemBundle1, itemBundle2))`, those are still `null`. You should move these 2 bundles out of eventBundle's `apply`:

```kotlin
override fun trackListViewEvent() {
    val itemBundle1 = Bundle().apply {
        putString(Param.ITEM_NAME, "name1")
        putString(Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Category")
        putString(Param.PRICE, "49.95")
        putString(Param.CURRENCY, "EUR")
    }

    val itemBundle2 = Bundle().apply {
        putString(Param.ITEM_NAME, "name2")
        putString(Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Category")
        putString(Param.PRICE, "89.95")
        putString(Param.CURRENCY, "EUR")
    }

    val eventBundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString(Param.ITEM_LIST_ID, "1234567890")
        putString(Param.ITEM_LIST_NAME, "WhateverListName")
        putString(Param.PRICE, "125.60")
        putString(Param.CURRENCY, "EUR")
        putParcelableArray(Param.ITEMS, arrayOf(itemBundle1, itemBundle2))
    }
    tracking.logEvent(Event.VIEW_ITEM_LIST, eventBundle)
}
```

---

Old answer:

With your current code, the inferred type of `arrayOf(itemBundle1, itemBundle2)` is `Array<Bundle>`.

You should enforce Kotlin to use `Array<Parcelable>`:

```kotlin
putParcelableArray(Param.ITEMS, arrayOf<Parcelable>(itemBundle1, itemBundle2))
```

Comment: Still getting the same error in the log: "W/FA-SVC: Param value can't be null: items" and not appearing in the debug view.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is solved for me when I update all the Firebase libraries to the newest Version.